# Comments when "not an answer" is processed

Tags: support

Earlier today I flagged an answer as "not an answer" and it's since been moved to a comment along with my original comment under the answer. The question I'm discussing is:

[How do I exchange LCD display with 7-segment LED's?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/42911/how-do-i-exchange-lcd-display-with-7-segment-leds)

In case anything changes in the comments area the 'answer' was:

> during 1996 l have found on an electronics
>   magazine(probably'electronics for you' or elektor,i don't rember) on a
>   project of an electronic"lcd clock"based on a wrist watch. where the
>   signals for lcd display were amplified by using some pairs of SL100and
>   SK-100 to drive 3&1/2 LED display connected in matix arrangement. I am
>   still searching for the project.

During the first post review process I made the following comment and flagged it:

> Welcome to the EE.SE! Until you locate the project and can provide
>   further information though you shouldn't really post this as an
>   answer. Once you have enough reputation it would be suitable as a
>   comment but for the moment it would be better to hold-off until you've
>   found the solution that answers the question.

Now I'm wondering if I delete my comment if the user will still receive any feedback if they haven't happened to be on the site since? I thought I'd leave the comment for the moment in case it means they won't get feedback but at the same time it may confuse the OP that it's somehow directed at them.

Comment: I'm guessing your comment got automatically moved as a comment to the question when the answer it was originally a comment to got deleted.  I flagged for moderator attention.

Comment: @OlinLathrop, thanks yes I'd noticed that before and no doubt the reason. I was mainly wondering if I should delete my moved comment which I could do myself or if it's better to leave in case the person that posted the answer won't see it next time they log in. I didn't know if they get another sort of notification of why the answer was moved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That was our fault. When we convert an answer to a comment we get a nice little check box to migrate all comments to that answer also, as sometimes the OP will get in a back and forth discussion there. When the answer was converted to comment your comment was migrated also.

All fixed now. Your comment is still on the users answer that was deleted and it will notify them there.

Comment: That was MY fault :). I actually wanted to leave the comment in order for the answerer to receive your feedback, but I didn't considered the fact that the OP could take it as a comment to his question.

Comment: @clabacchio I did the same thing as I was learning the tool, they still get the comments on their answer even though you migrated the content, it just deletes the answer.